# Python Syntax Error, can't find a solution to indentions

Tags: python

Been having issues with one of my scripts. When I run the script, I get the following message under line 23:

```
SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

I have tried using Anaconda to replace any tabs with 4/8 spaces but no success.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Cheers.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

sensor = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

previous_state = False
current_state = False

try:

    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        previous_state = current_state
        current_state = GPIO.input(sensor)
        if current_state != previous_state:
            new_state = "HIGH" if current_state else "LOW"
            print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensor, new_state))
            import smtplib

        smtpUser = 'rpigroupproject@gmail.com'
        smtpPass = '<password>'

        toAdd = 'rpigroupproject@gmail.com'
        fromAdd = smtpUser

        subject = 'ALERT!'
        header = 'To: ' + toAdd + '\n' + 'From: ' + \
            fromAdd + '\n' + 'Subject:' + subject
        body = 'Motion was detected...'

        print header + '\n' + body

        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

        s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.ehlo()

        s.login(smtpUser, smtpPass)
        s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header + '\n' + body)

        s.quit()

except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: May be it is because of the line containing "smtpPass = 'W1r3l355'". Seems to be indented more than needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is with the indentation fixed. You should configure your editor so you don't get this error again.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

sensor = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

previous_state = False
current_state = False

try:

    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        previous_state = current_state
        current_state = GPIO.input(sensor)
        if current_state != previous_state:
            new_state = "HIGH" if current_state else "LOW"
            print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensor, new_state))
            import smtplib

    smtpUser = 'rpigroupproject@gmail.com'
    smtpPass = 'W1r3l355'

    toAdd = 'rpigroupproject@gmail.com'
    fromAdd = smtpUser

    subject = 'ALERT!'
    header = 'To: ' + toAdd + '\n' + 'From: ' + fromAdd + '\n' + 'Subject:' + subject
    body = 'Motion was detected...'

    print header + '\n' + body

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()

    s.login(smtpUser, smtpPass)
    s.sendmail(fromAdd, toAdd, header + '\n' + body)

    s.quit() 

except:
   GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you using a custom identation, but just for the sake of testing I would advice to reset any customization and use *tabs*.

For example, this is a sample of your code below. You can see that identation between *try-while*, and what follows *while* is not consistent

```
try:
   while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    previous_state = current_state
    current_state = GPIO.input(sensor)
```

This is how it looks with consistent identation:

```
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        previous_state = current_state
        current_state = GPIO.input(sensor)
```

Comment: PEP8 suggests 4 spaces. Most editors convert Tabs to 4 spaces. I don't think it's helpful to suggest the OP uses tabs unless they know they're being converted to spaces.

Comment: Good point. I was trying to convey to reset any customizacion to test. I would assume any decent code editor would handle tabs properly